# How do I make Yeoman not use the parent directory name for the application .js file?

Tags: configuration, angularjs, yeoman

When I use `yeoman init angular:all`to bootstrap my app, yeoman uses the name of the directory I'm calling it from as the name of the main application .js file. I.e. if I'm running the command in `/Users/myusername/dev/projects/my-angular-app`, then the file `app/scripts/my-angular-app.js` is created as the main .js file for the app.

If I simply rename the root directory, then using Yeoman to add routes won't work, as it can no longer find the .js file it created. I've tried adding the name of the app as a parameter when invoking the Yeoman init command, but that doesn't work.

I've tried doing the init command in a directory with the name I want the app to have, and then renaming the directory afterwards. But it seems Yeoman reads the name of that directory every time it's invoked, so after changing the name of the directory, Yeoman is no longer able to create routes for me as it can't find the .js file with the same name as the root directory.

How can I make Yeoman use a different name for the my-angular-app.js file?

Comment: Um... Who downvoted, and why?

Comment: So, am I the only one with OCD when it comes to naming things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an open [ticket](https://github.com/yeoman/generators/issues/82) about it, please weigh in your thoughts there.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is possible but you might want to have a look at the Gruntfile.js and replace all the instances in the config were it is storing the old path and replace it with the new path.  I am not sure if that will work as I have never tried but it might based on my understanding of Grunt.

I am like you, I like to have things named the way I want which why I don't use Yeoman even though I would love to (like they say, it is opinionated, just too opinionated for me), I have a few custom built grunt tasks that give me most of the functionality I need (mainly auto compile of SASS/TypeScript, minifying CSS/JS, and concating CSS/JS files).

Comment: That's kind of the main problem - there's no reference to the root folder in Gruntfile.js. It simply uses the name of the root folder at the time of execution. As I understand it, Grunt is a framework that Yeoman builds upon, so maybe I can find something about it in the Grunt docs or something - a way to override that behaviour. There are several ways to work around this, but none are ideal. Thanks for pitching in though :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with generator-angular.

Currently, the app name is taken from the bower **component.json** file.  If you are using the more recent convention of naming this file **bower.json**, the app name will fall back to the directory name.

Rename **bower.json** to **component.json** until support for the new naming scheme makes it into generator-angular.

It looks like these changes have already been made but have yet to be merged into the master branch:  [renaming-deprecated-component_json](https://github.com/robinboehm/generator-angular/branches/renaming-deprecated-component_json)

Comment: I was using Yeoman 0.9.6, so it is component.json already. And the first thing I tried was putting the name I wanted in there, but it didn't work. There was absolutely no documentation on how to specify it in that file, so it might have been supported and I just did it incorrectly. However, I'm no longer using Yeoman; I've just gone with vanilla Grunt.js and Bower. I may use Yeoman again in the future if I do more smaller projects and the 1.x releases have stabilized.

Comment: Ok, I confirmed on my own project that this was the issue, but I'm using Yeoman 1.0 beta.6 and generator-angular 0.2.2, but it looks like you had a different issue.